# How can I block a strange string starting with a '?' using Robot.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

Google has somehow indexed a series of strange URLs from my old website, all of them begin with  www.example.com/?c%2

Since this is not a query I'm not sure how to redirect or block it.

How could I safely block this url pattern using Robot.txt

http://example.com/?c%25253EenGtcHW6eHmu%25255BYNvZ3F%25253E'dmjdlgsbve%25253E2'lfzxpset%25253EQsftt'sbol%25253E2'f%25253Evt%25253Cvt%25253C79%25253C2%25253C2%25253C66179895%25253Cyofumboefsy%25253C2%25253C29249%25253A'vsm%25253Eiuuq%2525264B%2525263G%2525263Gxxx%25252Fopdmjdlz%25252Fdpn%2525263G'gffe%25253Eopqbz'qsjdf%25253E'tbq%25253Eefb6882bg9fgf3b9%25253A6c79b4bb5ce972b'zbsht%25253Exxx%25252Fopdmjdlz%25252Fdpn

Comment: These are bots probing for vulnerable versions of common software. They won't be following robots.txt

Comment: But as I said, Google has somehow indexed these URLs as duplicate content.  I would like to block/redirect them for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite them in `.htaccess`. Anything after a query start would be processed as an empty query string. Replace strings where appropriate:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]
```

Additionally in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) you can [specify to Google which parameters to ignore](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1235687).

Comment: Thanks AbsoluteƵERØ, but that gave me the following error "This webpage has a redirect loop" it also made the URL even longer with the following pattern..  http://example.com/?c%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253EenGtcHW6eHmu%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525255BYNvZ3F%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253E'lfzxpset%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253EEjhjubm%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252CBewfsujtjoh'sbol%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253E2'f%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253E

Comment: @Hazeus I've updated my answer. This works on my server. If you're still having a loop it's likely a conflicting rule.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.  Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer up.

Comment: @Hazeus It's cool. You should be able to mark it as answered though.